# Switch Case vs. Conditional?

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, switch-statement

I found this post: [Switch case with three parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328467/switch-case-with-three-parameters) and I was considering using switch case passing multiple parameters like this:

```
switch (array($var1, $var2, $var3)) {
case array(true, false, false):
    echo "hello";
    break;
}
```

There seems to be some question as to whether this is the most efficient way of doing this. The mood seems to be that an if conditional is more appropriate. But, when I look at the conditional I'm writing, I'm not sure? For example this feels messy (note that I've removed about 6 other conditionals to keep from boring you):

```
if ( 
  csz == "google" || 
  csz == "bing" || 
  csz == "yahoo" || 
  csz == "dogpile" || 
  csz == "millionshort" && 
  cs == '' ) { 
    $("li.phone").replaceWith('<li class="phone">' + phoneNaturalSearch + '</li>');
}
else if ( 
  csz == "facebook" && 
  cs == '' ) { 
    $("li.phone").replaceWith('<li class="phone">' + phoneFacebook + '</li>');
}
else if ( 
  csz == "google-plus" || 
  csz == "plus" ) { 
    $("li.phone").replaceWith('<li class="phone">' + phoneGooglePlus + '</li>');
}
// Snipped out other conditionals
else { 
    $("li.phone").replaceWith('<li class="phone">' + phoneDefault + '</li>');
}
```

Would switch with multiple parameters be more efficient here, or would I experience a performance hit? I guess I should write the code and see if it's actually less messy, but I thought I'd bounce it off of the gurus first.

Comment: [build a jsPerf test case](http://jsperf.com/if-statement-with-many-ors) and find out yourself. It might depend on the browser that's running it.

Comment: I've never used this tool. Thanks for pointing me to it!

Comment: I don't get how this works?  You can't just compare two arrays http://jsfiddle.net/acXV4/1/

Comment: It's somewhat complicated to explain but you're right, an array may be more appropriate. Basically, I have parameters extracted from a URL (which may or may not exist), and parameters extracted from the Google Analytics cookie. The more important parameters are those passed through a URL because this means that the incoming link was most likely from a paid advertisement. The less important are the parameters from the GA utmz cookie. I'm testing to see which are present and which are not and presenting the user with the appropriate phone number to call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel if you have these many conditions I prefer to use switch statements which makes your code cleaner and easier to understand..
You can omit the break's for the conditions that fall for this particular category...

```
var phoneType= '';

switch(csz){ 
  case "google" : 
  case  "bing" : 
  case "yahoo" :
  case "dogpile"  : 
  case "millionshort" : 
    if (cs==''){ 
        phoneType = phoneNaturalSearch ;
        break;
    }
    else {
        goto case "facebook";
    }
  case "facebook" :
    if (cs==''){ 
        phoneType = phoneFacebook  ;
        break;
    }
    else {
        goto case "google-plus";
    }
  case "google-plus" :
  case "plus"  : 
    phoneType = phoneGooglePlus ;
    break;
  default : 
    phoneType = phoneDefault  ;
    break;
}

$("li.phone").replaceWith('<li class="phone">' + phoneType + '</li>');
```

Comment: I like the way that looks! It's much cleaner and more what I have in mind. I'm going to give it whirl - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Talking about neater solutions, another way of doing it is to keep them in a 2 dimensional array and retrieving the element index.

Check this out :

```
var csz= 'amazon';

var groups = [['google','yahoo','bing'],['facebook','orkut','hi5','zurker'],['amazon','bestbuy','sears']];
var groupIndex = getIndexOf(groups,csz);
if(groupIndex ==1){
    //code here
    alert("1");
}else if(groupIndex ==2){
    //code here
    alert("2");
}else if(groupIndex ==3){
    //code here
    alert("3");
}

function getIndexOf(myArray,element){
    for(var i=0;i<groups.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<groups[i].length;j++){
            if(myArray[i][j]==element){
                return i;  
            }
        }
    }        
    return -1;
}
```