# Syntax for multiple switch statement to detect server environment

Tags: php

I need to detect different server environments in my site's config file. Up until now I was fine with detecting them using only the server's address.

```
switch ( $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']){
    case '127.0.0.1':
    // stuff
    break;
    case '111.222.333.444';
    // stuff
    break;
}
```

But I now need to test my environment against both the `SERVER_ADDR` and `SERVER_NAME`. I'm no php'er, so I've had a stab at

```
switch ( $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] && $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ){
    case ('127.0.0.1','local'):
    // stuff
    break;
    case ('111.222.333.444','gimmesomefunk.com');
    // stuff
    break;
}
```

But it's obviously wrong. Any clues?

Comment: P.S. You put a colon (`:`) after `case` statements, not a semi-colon (`;`).

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat, you're right. That was a typo!

Comment: @sjagr, you are indeed right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep using `switch`, you'll have to combine both to one variable like this:

```
switch (array($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'], $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])){
    case array('127.0.0.1', 'local'):
    // stuff
    break;
    case array('111.222.333.444', 'gimmesomefunk.com'):
    // stuff
    break;
}
```

However, the more normal way would be to use `if`, `elseif`:

```
if ( $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1' && $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'local' ) {
    // stuff
} elseif ( $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '111.222.333.444' && $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'gimmesomefunk.com' ) {
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: Can you switch on an array?  Does that work?  I've never tried it.

Comment: Just editted it, when I saw another [Stackoverflow solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328467/switch-case-with-three-parameters). Before, I had used string concatenation in my answer. Never tried array-switch myself.

Comment: I didn't realize `switch` worked with arrays, that's kinda neat.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it s the best method but you can concatenate values like this :

```
switch ( $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ){
    case ('127.0.0.1local');
    // stuff
    break;
    case ('111.222.333.444gimmesomefunk.com');
    // stuff
    break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this, as what you're actually entering the `switch` statement with is a boolean (`true`) because you're saying "is this string truthy, and this string truthy":

```
var_dump($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] && $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) // bool(true)
```

You could simply do the following by using an `if` statement instead (you don't *have* to use `$address` and `$name`, but in my opinion it becomes more readable):

```
$address = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
$name = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

if ($address === '127.0.0.1' && $name === 'local') {
    // Stuff
} else if ($address === '111.222.333.444' && $name === 'gimmesomefunc.com') {
    // Other stuff
}
```